# ./configure and make problems on macOS

Tags: macos, homebrew, configure

I am trying to get [QuantumEspresso](https://github.com/QEF/q-e)

I downloaded it, went into the folder and try to use

```
./configure
```

but got the error

```
(base) localhost:q-e myname$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
checking ARCH... mac686
checking setting AR... ... /anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar
checking setting ARFLAGS... ... ruv
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgfortran... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking for nagfor... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking whether the Fortran compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/myname/Documents/QuantumEspresso/new_folder/q-e':
configure: error: Fortran compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Apparently, I don't have some parts like **gfortran**. Where do I get those missing parts for MAC?

Comment: Have you tried reading http://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/user_guide/node7.html…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the Homebrew package manager.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2. Use Homebrew to install `gcc` (includes `gfortran`)

```
brew install gcc
```